# SwiftUI - How to delete row in Entity in CoreData

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to develop an application to enter values into an entity that are displayed in a list. But when I delete them from the list, they are not deleted in the database. Do you have a solution?

```
struct ViewList: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @State var newName: String = ""

    @FetchRequest(
        entity: ItProduct.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ItProduct.name, ascending: true)]
    ) var list: FetchedResults<ItProduct>


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("I insert the name of the list", text: $newName)
                Button(action: {
                    if self.newName != "" {self.add()}
                    }) { Image(systemName: "plus")}
            }
            List {
                ForEach(list, id: \.self) { i in
                    ViewItem(product: i)
                }.onDelete { indexSet in
                    for index in indexSet {
                        self.context.delete(self.list[index])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if things are setup properly then you code should work.
Except... if maybe you are looking for data persistence between app launches, in which case you need to save the `CoreData` context at some time.

```
try? self.context.save()
```

#### Solution:

```
.onDelete { indexSet in
    for index in indexSet {
        self.context.delete(self.list[index])
        try? self.context.save()
    }
}
```

Comment: @MxM Glad to help :)